# C: Is there any wrong understanding about short-circuit evaluation?

Tags: c, short-circuit-evaluation

Hi I have little confused about logical operator.

According to KNK C chapter 5 exercise 3-4.

```
int i=1;
int j=1;
int k=1;
    
printf("%d\n",++i || ++j && ++k);
printf("%d %d %d",i,j,k);
```

I thought the result is 1\n 2 1 2 due to the short -circuit evaluation
like ((++i || ++j) && ++k ).

But the answer is 1\n 2 1 1.

Why does variable k increase?

Comment: `&&` has a higher precedence than `||`, so it's `++i || (++k && ++j)`. So the result should be `1\n 2 1 1`.

Comment: Where do you get `1\n 1 1 1`? `i` cannot be `1`.

Comment: This was wrongly closed as a duplicate, since the so-called “short-circuit evaluation“ would produce output of “1” and “2 1 1”, not the “1” and “1 1 1” reported. I am tempted to reopen it so we can close it with the proper status but will refrain for now since it is probably a typo or other reporting error. But voters should check that problems really are a duplicate before closing as a duplicate. Somethings real problems are missed in rushes to judgement.

Comment: sorry i is 2. My mistake. I edited it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

From [C Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence):

| Precedence | Operator | Description | Associativity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | `&&` | Logical AND | Left-to-right |
| 12 | `||` | Logical OR | Left-to-right |

Since `&&` has precedence 11 and `||` has 12, the expression `++i || ++j && ++k` is equal to this:

```
++i || (++j && ++k)
```

Left-to-right associativity makes it evaluate `++i` first, concludes that it's `true` and short-circuits so `(++j && ++k)` will not be evaluated.

The result is therefore

```
1
2 1 1
```

Comment: Oh I was mistaken precedence! Thank you.